# NSURLConnection finished with error iOS13 simulator and MACOS 10.14.6

Tags: ios-simulator, nsurlconnection, ios13, xcode11

My project is working on Xcode10 simulator but not in Xcode 11 simulator.Getting error as in below screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely caused by updated ATS restrictions in iOS 13, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176

You can get further details about problematic TLS-connections / -Certificates on the console via `nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://www.example.com`, see [Identifying the source of blocked connections](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections/identifying_the_source_of_blocked_connections)

An easy option to also check your server's TLS-config is https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Try disabling ATS at all via setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = true` in your Info.plist, see [NSAppTransportSecurity](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33). If that works, try to detect the exact problem, solve it and then remove the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads entry.